# Calculated column based on other calculated column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have code that will sum data for the hours column based on a description and then will sum hours based on the supervisor column.  I would like to add a calculated column that will take the first sum and divide it by the second sum to give me a percentage.  Here is my code with what I think is the right path for the percent column, but I can't get it to work.  Any help is appreciated!

```
SELECT sap.Description, 
       Sum(main.Hours) AS SumOfHours, 
       main.supervisor1email AS SupervisorEmail, 
       (SELECT SUM(sub.hours) 
        FROM   v_MES_TcActivities sub
        WHERE  sub.costctr = '106330' 
        AND    sub.AttCode Not Like 'MEAL'
        AND    sub.clockin Between dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) and dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
        AND    sub.supervisor1email = main.supervisor1email 
       ) AS TotalHours, 
       (SELECT Sum(subsub.hours) / TotalHours AS 'Percent'
       ) AS Percent
FROM v_MES_TcActivities AS main
  LEFT JOIN t_SAP_AttCodes AS sap ON main.AttCode = sap.Code
WHERE  main.AttCode Not Like 'MEAL' 
AND    main.CostCtr Like '106330' 
AND    main.ClockIn Between dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) and dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))

GROUP BY sap.Description, 
         main.supervisor1email, 
         Percent
ORDER BY main.supervisor1email
```

[Here is the before code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk5Yx.png)

[Here is what I am looking to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWKAK.png)

Comment: What does "can't get it to work" mean? Are you getting an error? Are the values incorrect? As posted this query is nearly impossible to read because the formatting is quite challenging. You might take a look here to improve your question. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Subqueries or windowing functions are not allowed in calculated columns and hence you might need to create view for this

Comment: @KannanKandasamy I think they mean a derived column, not a computed column.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Screenshots of current code, and what I would like to see have been added.

Comment: SQL is a set-based language. A lot of its constructs are designed so that parallelism can be achieved "for free". For instance, all expressions within a single `SELECT` clause are evaluated (effectively) at the "same time" - this means there cannot be dependencies *between* such expressions since none of the *results* are available when the evaluations are taking place.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well

```
SELECT Description,
       SumOfHours,
       SupervisorEmail,
       TotalHours,
       SumSubsubHr/TotalHours AS 'Percentage'
FROM (
            SELECT sap.Description, 
                   Sum(main.Hours) AS SumOfHours, 
                   main.supervisor1email AS SupervisorEmail, 
                   (SELECT SUM(sub.hours) 
                    FROM v_MES_TcActivities sub
                    WHERE sub.costctr='106330' AND sub.AttCode Not Like 'MEAL' AND sub.clockin Between dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) and dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
                    AND sub.supervisor1email = main.supervisor1email 
                   ) AS TotalHours, 
                  Sum(sub.hours) AS 'SumSubsubHr'

          FROM v_MES_TcActivities AS main
          LEFT JOIN t_SAP_AttCodes AS sap ON main.AttCode = sap.Code
          WHERE main.AttCode Not Like 'MEAL' 
          AND main.CostCtr Like '106330' 
          AND main.ClockIn Between dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) and dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
          GROUP BY sap.Description, main.supervisor1email
)t
```

Comment: I got an error that says "the multi-part identifier "subsub.hours" could not be bound"

Comment: Now it says the same thing with "sub.hours" could not be bound